# Visual Studio 2012 - Windows Azure : connection string not working (no database interaction)

Tags: azure, connection, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to put my Visual Studio 2012 MVC 4 project online using the Cloud Technology provided by Windows Azure.
Although i can get to my website (it uploads well and is accessible), I can't manage to make the data connection work.
For exemple, when I try to register a new user to my live application, it returns me a simple mistake : "A mistake happened while handling your request" (that's a translation from french, though... --')

I've followed a bunch of tutorial all around the web, but none seems to make things work.
Here's the connection string I actually use :

```
 <add name="yoombysql"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=tcp:rmy11na948.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=yoombysql;Integrated Security=False;User Id=yoomby;Password=PASSWORD;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

It's not the only thing I've tried, but i'm running out of ideas... So if anyone had a hint or a clue on this...
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your control panel for the DB rmy11na948 on the right side under "Manage allowed ip addresses" you have checked WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES = "YES" and if you are accessing Azure SQL outside of Azure, you need to add your specific IP address for testing.

**UPDATE**: You should add the full userId as well `User Id=yoomby@rmy11na948;`

Again, from the portal on the right side click "Show connection strings", copy the ADO.NET connection string and replace the {your_password_here}.  If that fails, then walk through the steps at [Windows Azure SQL Database Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx).

**UPDATE-2**: For Entity Framework connections, read [How to: Connect to Windows Azure SQL Database Using the ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951633.aspx) and read [Entity Framework and SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg190738.aspx)

Comment: Windows Azure Services is on Yes. My IP adress has been added to the authorized IPs, but I still get the same error...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though. Any other ideas ?

Comment: is the IP address your external IP address?  Also, are you using Entity Framrework?

Comment: The IP is my external IP, yeap (the one i get from whatsmyip.com, for exemple. And the same that Azure proposes me).
And yes, I am using Entity Framework. Can it change anything ?

Comment: then your connection string is wrong - you are using an ADO.NET connection string read How to: Connect to Windows Azure SQL Database Using the ADO.NET Entity Framework @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951633.aspx

Comment: It worked ! I just copied the ADO.NET, modified my password, and it worked !